# Bootstrap Slider and Keyframes on IE10 - CSS3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

i´am using keyframes to animate the Feature Slider of the website.

Carousel is working fine. Animations as well except with IE10.

Keyframne - This will determine the movement of down to up.

```
@-webkit-keyframes downup { from  { opacity:0; top:500px;}to {top:0;opacity:.9;}}
@-moz-keyframes downup { from  { opacity:0; top:500px;}to{top:0;opacity:.9;}} 
@keyframes downup{ from  { opacity:0; top:500px;}to {top:0;opacity:.9;}}

.updown {
position: relative; 
opacity:0;
animation:downup 1s forwards;
-webkit-animation:mymove 1s forwards;
-moz-animation:mymove 1s forwards;}
```

IE10 shows the firsts 4 content in the loop but when he starts again at first slides de info .updown are not showed. You can check the  slider under constrution here: http://ndsim.esec.pt/nova/index.html

Any help would be awesome thanks.

**SOLUTION**

its working now. i ´had some bootstrap conflict class´s… separated them and now its working.. was making like this

```
<div id=”myCarousel” class=”carousel slide fade-in one”>
```

and changed to

```
<div id=”myCarousel” class=”carousel slide”>
<div class=”fade-in one”>
```

dunno what happened for sure but was some sort of IE conflict.

Comment: its working now. i ´had some bootstrap conflict class´s… separated them and now its working.. was making like this

<div id=”myCarousel” class=”carousel slide fade-in one”>
and changed to
<div id=”myCarousel” class=”carousel slide”>
<div class=”fade-in one”>

dunno what happened for sure but was some sort of IE10 conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help on my grammar madth3 :P